# Importing data with sstableloader, getting streaming error "StreamReceiveException: java.lang.AssertionError"

Tags: cassandra

I am using sstableloader to import data into Cassandra, and I'm getting the following error in one of the Cassandra nodes (one of the coordinator ).
I don't understand what the error is about. Is there any other log that I can get more info?

```
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/10.15.xx.xx:7000-106a5282] 2023-02-28 17:36:58,265 StreamSession.java:675 - [Stream #618be3f0-b783-11ed-89bb-a1d38c73e6d8] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.15.xx.xx:7000
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveException: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:38)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingInboundHandler$StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamingInboundHandler.java:172)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Chunk.<init>(CompressionMetadata.java:504)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$ChunkSerializer.deserialize(CompressionMetadata.java:542)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$ChunkSerializer.deserialize(CompressionMetadata.java:532)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CompressionInfo$CompressionInfoSerializer.deserialize(CompressionInfo.java:194)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CompressionInfo$CompressionInfoSerializer.deserialize(CompressionInfo.java:166)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraStreamHeader$CassandraStreamHeaderSerializer.deserialize(CassandraStreamHeader.java:212)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraStreamHeader$CassandraStreamHeaderSerializer.deserialize(CassandraStreamHeader.java:192)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraStreamHeader$CassandraStreamHeaderSerializer.deserialize(CassandraStreamHeader.java:161)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraIncomingFile.read(CassandraIncomingFile.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:53)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

With streaming operations, there is always a source and a destination node. You will need to check the logs on both source and destination for clues.

Use the session ID (which in your case is `618be3f0-b783-11ed-89bb-a1d38c73e6d8`) when searching through the logs to help narrow it down so you don't have to go through all the log entries.

As a side note, make sure you always include the software version when asking for help because the behaviour differs across versions. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Erick .The data is from Cassandra 3.11.5v .  The source is 4.0.4v (the executor server that runs the sstableloader ), and the destination node 4.0.4v .   when you write "searching through the logs" are you referring to  /var/log/cassandra/system.log ?

Comment: The table is 250G and this is the only error that I can see in the Cassandra logs `ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/10.15.xx.xx:7000-6bea42ad] 2023-03-01 14:21:32,939 StreamSession.java:675 - [Stream #c83dd180-b837-11ed-b4c9-cdf5504870fd] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.15.xx.xx:7000
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveException: org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingInputPlus$InputTimeoutException    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:60)    `

Comment: Like I said, you need to check the logs on both the source and destination nodes. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your particular situation allows to use an alternate approach, consider leveraging [**DSBulk** utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/getStartedDsbulk.html) to perform the unload of data from source and loading it into your target cluster.

Which could be as simple as,

```
./dsbulk unload -k keyspace_name -t table_name -url /directory/path/ -h '["source_ip1","source_ip2"]' [-u username -p password]
```

and then performing,

```
./dsbulk load -k keyspace_name -t table_name -url /directory/path/ -h '["target_ip1","target_ip2"]' [-u username -p password]
```

Comment: Using dsbulk will take a significant amount of time because this table has a size of 250G

Comment: With a right-size client machine and configs, I've seen, in many instances, where DSBulk has performed really well with sizes much greater than `250GB`. Aside of DSBulk, you could leverage this alternative approach of using [Cassandra Data Migrator](https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-data-migrator) as an option (or) try and debug on both `source` & `target` clusters logs to determine the root cause with the *SSTableLoader*. Another alternative, is to leverage [OpsCenter's](docs.datastax.com) restore from backup mechanism **if** your source & target clusters are of DataStax Enterprise (DSE).

Answer (score 0):

After configuring this parameter, the issue was successfully resolved. `export MAX_HEAP_SIZE=12G`